# removing huge spaces between sections

Tags: spacing

I am currently using a template from latex and I am trying to remove these spaces (image in the link below as the image is very large).

I tried to use `\vspace{-30cm}` and `\\` but it seems like it has some default settings somewhere and it doesn't affect the template.

[image: the image]

Here is the code of one of the sections.

```
\documentclass[10pt,A4,english]{article}
\cvsection{Ansættelseshistorik}
\cvevent
\cvsection{Projekter}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a compilable [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927)? This would be extremely helpful for us to be able to help you!

Comment: Hi, I removed unecessary items, can it still be improved for the minimal example?

Comment: Well, it is tremendously important to know which `\documentclass` you use and which packages. If the `\documentclass` or the packages you use are not included in a regular TeX installation, please refer to the source where you downloaded them. I have the feeling, that you used one of these CV templates from Overleaf? Please tell us more! =)

Comment: From the image you posted: Did you maybe use [this template](https://github.com/philipempl/modern-latex-cv)?

Comment: Please don't point to other places on the web. I can't see anything on your `imgur.com` post because of its privacy problems. You can show graphics within your question by clicking on the graphics tag. Tags look a little like `B I 8 `` {} [ ]  etc.`, where the [ ] is the graphics tag.

Comment: Yes exactly! Except I didn't download it from Github but directly from the template page of the website. I have included the documentclass

Comment: You use the `article` documentclass but that does not define the command `\cvsection`. I have no idea what you have done, and maybe others have the same problem with your question. Please provide a complete MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: Okay, well, I took a look into the code of this template and ... how should I put it ... I would suggest only to use it if you are very familiar with how LaTeX works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me try to answer. The template you obviously use is not part of one of the official TeX distributions, but [available at Overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-latex-cv/qmdwjvcrcrph). My first impression is that it has been written quite hastily and therefore contains a lot of sub-optimally coded stuff which is not easy to handle. So, it would be best that you use it only if you are very familiar with how LaTeX works.

One example of strange coding in this template is the fact that the macro `\cvevent` is defined with seven arguments. In the body of the template, which contains a lot of example code, however, almost never all these seven arguments are given, which leads to unstable code that quickly breaks when editing something.

A call of this macro should actually be like this (each, possibly empty, argument being wrapped in curly brackets):

```
\cvevent
{Sep. 2015 -- Okt. 2015}
{some title}
{some locatiion}
{}
{}
{}
{}
```

Now, to finally answer your question about how to remove the large gaps: If you use this macro properly and state each of its seven arguments, you may indeed place something like `\vspace{-5mm}` behind it (that is, behind the last closed curly bracket) to decrease the space to the next paragraph.